# How to replace with leading zeros in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

In an Excel file, I need to replace, say, "foo" by "007".

I selected all the file and I explicitly put the cell format to be in **Text** mode.

So, why it replaces me "foo" by "7" and not by "007" as I said it :( ?

[image]

Comment: what are the exact steps you've tried to do it?

Comment: open the excel file, select a column, then Ctrl+H, from "foo" to "007"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apparently, excel interprets "007" as number when replacing. So you could use `'007` in the replace-dialog, so it shows your wanted result.

Comment: what does mean `'007`? I mean, I need just `007`.. I put the format as *Text*, why should it treat as number?

Comment: The `'` interprets the number as text. You don't see it in your cell.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a single quote in front of your leading number - ex. '01234
It will take the number as-is literally and the quote will not show in the field.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the cell, look at controls at top of page, choose cell format.
Scroll until you see "numbers" a better choice than text.. If the choice is close to what you want you can use the examples to make your own. Once you find the correct expression it will give you "007" or any number you type to the left side of the expression  but it must be seen on the far left of the cell. If you want all the numbers below that cell to have the same properties, select "column" instead of "cell" You will be presented with the same numerical formatting choices.Just change the "XXX" to "007" then the rest of the cells also will show "007, "then whatever you put in as numbers. If you want to add text why not just start another column next to the one that you just made and set the text cells as you want. You can set the text cells to show or hide a lengthy explanation of the number entered in the cell next to it.
Just suggestions,Goodluck. There are small differences in versions of Excel but do not worry, just go to the help files. Then try support links. Then if you learn something help someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace with `=text(7;"000")` (yes, including the quotation marks)
2. Replace with 7, select the cells or the whole column. Go to cell formatting > Custom > type in `000`
3. Replace with `'007`